# CSS TextArea - giving different opacity to each visible line

Tags: javascript, html, css

SO i have a textarea in my html

```
<textarea id="log" class="txtbx-log" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Now i'm using this to display a running log in real time. I would like the first line to be 100% opacity, and each further line's opacity reducing by 10.

is this possible to do with css/javascript?

i am aware of the possibility to make multiple divs and give each its own opacity, and move the position of the divs / opacity as new log messages come in.

but that would lead to ugly code to move the log messages from one div to the other. Is there an easier way to do this.

** EDIT **

as of now, i am simply prepending the log messages like this.

```
on_chunk_uploaded: function() {
                        $('#log').prepend("<span>Chunk finished uploading</span>")
}
```

Comment: Nope. `<textarea>` element doesn't have any possibility to have different styles for text inside. I'd emulate the `<textarea>` behaviour by using `<div>` with `overflow: auto;`.

Comment: Can you do this with divs or spans instead? How many lines do you need to show at once/should the user be able to scroll? If you can do it with divs, it would be pretty simple.

Comment: Why not just append the new div to the bottom and then change the classes of the divs, would be much easier and cleaner or prepend the div and just use css nth child selectors then the top divs will always be the opacity you want

Comment: i can put it into one div. can an opacity gradient like thing be added via css? I don't want to put into multiple divs though..

Comment: I also want to show only 10 lines or so. no scrolling will be allowed.

Comment: You could use a CSS gradient as an overlay... but then the user would have trouble selecting the text beneath it. Best would be to have each line be a separate span and apply CSS with the nth-child selector.

Comment: This is possible with webkit masks, but I don't understand why you can't have multiple divs? This is not tricky and is how it would generally be done in javascript, via multiple divs or an unordered list. If you show us your code we could show you how you would re-factor it to work with multiple divs with different classes for the opacity...

Comment: If you really really can't refactor with divs/spans, take a look at this codepen... also may have issues. What you need is a nth-line selector, but it doesn't exist currently. http://cdpn.io/AifjK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this...

```
on_chunk_uploaded: function() {
    $('#log').prepend("<span>Chunk finished uploading</span>")
}
```

You could do it like this... (If you only have 10 messages shown per log as you stated?)

```
on_chunk_uploaded: function() {
    $('#log').prepend("<span>Chunk finished uploading</span>")

    // If there are now more than 10 log lines, remove the last one
    if($('#log span').length > 10){
        $('#log span:last').remove();
    }

    // Remove all classes from the log lines
    $('#log span').removeClass();
    var opacity = 100;

    // Cycle through each line and add decrementing opacity classes
    $.each($('#log span'), function(index, $element){
        $element.addClass('opacity-' + opacity);
        opacity = opacity - 10;
    });
}
```

Then add some appropriate CSS with opacity from opacity-100 to opacity 0... (**untested!**)

The CSS:

```
.opacity-100
{
   /* Opaque, doesn't need transparency... */
}
.opacity-90
{
   opacity: 0.9;
   filter:Alpha(opacity=90);
}
.opacity-80
{
   opacity: 0.8;
   filter:Alpha(opacity=80);
}
/* All the way down to 0... */
```

**Note: Edited code as I accidently appended the opacity with . instead of + (PHP habits)**